# VB.Net Simple Json Edit

Tags: json, vb.net

```
(Sorry my bad english.)
```

I installed JSON.Net(Newtonsoft) yesterday.
so i read documents.. examples.. but i cant do anything.

first, here is my json code.

```
{
    "profiles": {
        "164o": {
            "name": "164o",
            "lastVersionId": "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965",
            "launcherVisibilityOnGameClose": "keep the launcher open"
        },
        "BellCraft5": {
            "name": "BellCraft5",
            "gameDir": "C:\\Users\\HideHideHide\\AppData\\Roaming\\.custompacks\\BellCraft5",
            "lastVersionId": "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965",
            "javaArgs": "-Xmx2G -XX:PermSize\u003d128m -XX:MaxPermSize\u003d256m",
            "launcherVisibilityOnGameClose": "keep the launcher open"
        },
        "HideHideHide": {
            "name": "HideHideHide",
            "lastVersionId": "1.7.9_kr"
        },
        "TFC": {
            "name": "TFC",
            "gameDir": "C:\\Users\\HideHideHide\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\crazy",
            "lastVersionId": "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965",
            "launcherVisibilityOnGameClose": "hide launcher and re-open when game closes"
        },
        "Nooby": {
            "name": "Nooby",
            "gameDir": "C:\\Users\\HideHideHide\\AppData\\Roaming\\.custompacks\\172wepsv",
            "lastVersionId": "1.7.2-Forge10.12.2.1121",
            "launcherVisibilityOnGameClose": "keep the launcher open"
        },
        "OswinCraft": {
            "name": "OswinCraft",
            "gameDir": "C:\\Users\\HideHideHide\\AppData\\Roaming\\.custompacks\\OswinCraft",
            "lastVersionId": "1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965",
            "launcherVisibilityOnGameClose": "keep the launcher open"
        }
    },
    "selectedProfile": "OswinCraft",
    "clientToken": "HideHideHide-18ef-4b3a-a421-HideHideHide",
    "authenticationDatabase": {
        "HideHideHide": {
            "username": "dbcc@abcd.com",
            "accessToken": "HideHideHide",
            "userid": "HideHideHide",
            "uuid": "HideHideHide",
            "displayName": "HideHideHide"
        },
        "HideHideHide2": {
            "username": "abcd@dbcc.com",
            "accessToken": "HideHideHide",
            "userid": "HideHideHide",
            "uuid": "HideHideHide",
            "displayName": "HideHideHide"
        }
    },
    "selectedUser": "HideHideHide",
    "launcherVersion": {
        "name": "1.5",
        "format": 16
    }
}
```

Yeah, just one of game settings.
i want just make one profiles.

like,

```
"Test Profile": {
    "name": "Test Profile",
    "gameDir": "C:\\Test",
    "lastVersionId": "Test"
}
```

Yeah, i tried

```
Public Class Form
    Private Sub AnySub()
        Dim sJsonObj As JSON_Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_Object)(File.ReadAllText("C:\example.json"))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class JSON_Object
    Public profiles As Object
    Public selectedProfile As String
    Public clientToken As String
    Public authenticationDatabase As Object
    Public selectedUser As String
    Public launcherVersion As Object
End Class
```

but i cant.

anyone can help me?
(If you know about serialize it as a file, please teach me.)

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize `profiles` as a Dictionary, and add a new profile to it.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.IO

Public Class Profile
    Public name As String
    Public gameDir As String
    Public lastVersionId As String
    Public javaArgs As String
    Public launcherVisibilityOnGameClose As String
End Class

Public Class JSON_Object
    Public profiles As Dictionary(Of String, Profile) '' Object -> Dictionary
    Public selectedProfile As String
    Public clientToken As String
    Public authenticationDatabase As Object
    Public selectedUser As String
    Public launcherVersion As Object
End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim sJsonObj As JSON_Object =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_Object)(File.ReadAllText("C:\example.json"))

        ' Add a new profile.
        sJsonObj.profiles.Add("Test Profile", New Profile With {
                              .name = "Test Profile",
                              .gameDir = "C:\Test",
                              .lastVersionId = "Test"
                          })

        ' Serialize to JSON string.
        Dim settings As New JsonSerializerSettings
        settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        Dim strJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sJsonObj, settings)

        ' Write to file.
        File.WriteAllText("C:\your\writable\path\exampleNew.json", strJson)
    End Sub

End Module
```