# How to edit JSON file data in VisualBasic 2015

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I've data in JSON file:

```
{
"drivers":
{
    "92ca8cf9e45ee61186a6001e671f718d":
    {
        "DogovorN":"0503770761/10117",
        "DogovorData":"Some text",
        "DataRozhdenia":"some text",
        "MestoRozhdenia":"Some text",
        "PassportSeria":"0503",
        "PassportN":"770761",
        "DataVidachi":"01.03.2004",
        "PassportVidan":"Some text",
        "Adres":"some text",
        "Telefon":"some text",
        "RaschetniiSchet":"some text",
        "Poluchatel":"some Name",
        "Naznachenie":"",
        "BIK":"Some text"
    }
}
}
```

I need to add new record. Like this:

```
{
"drivers":
{
    "92ca8cf9e45ee61186a6001e671f718d":
    {
        "DogovorN":"0503770761/10117",
        "DogovorData":"01.01.2017",
        "DataRozhdenia":"17.12.1983",
        "MestoRozhdenia":"с.Ракушка, Ольгинского р-на, Приморского края",
        "PassportSeria":"0503",
        "PassportN":"770761",
        "DataVidachi":"01.03.2004",
        "PassportVidan":"Первореченским РУВД г.Владивостока",
        "Adres":"г.Владивосток, ул.Днепровская, 14, кв.4",
        "Telefon":"9147219161",
        "RaschetniiSchet":"40817810250000385310",
        "Poluchatel":"Калашников Александр Сергеевич",
        "Naznachenie":"",
        "BIK":"040813608"
    },
    "43kj5n43kj5nk5jn6jk36h5j45kb6kj4":
    {
        "DogovorN":"5664564/676756",
        "DogovorData":"Some text",
        "DataRozhdenia":"Some text",
        "MestoRozhdenia":"Some text",
        "PassportSeria":"Some text",
        "PassportN":"Some text",
        "DataVidachi":"Some text",
        "PassportVidan":"Some text",
        "Adres":"Some text",
        "Telefon":"Some text",
        "RaschetniiSchet":"Some text",
        "Poluchatel":"Some text",
        "Naznachenie":"Some text",
        "BIK":"Some text"
    }
}}
```

And also I need to cheange some values of properties. For example, change value of "PassportN" at "92ca8cf9e45ee61186a6001e671f718d" with "123456".

How can I do it in Visual Basic 2015 with Newtonsoft.json?

Reading code: (it works good and I have not questions about reading)

```
    Dim DrvFile As String = File.ReadAllText("Drivers.json")
    Dim DrvFileObj As JObject = JObject.Parse(DrvFile)
    Dim dataDrvFile As List(Of JToken) = DrvFileObj.Children().ToList
    Dim output As String = ""
    For Each Driver As JProperty In dataDrvFile
        Driver.CreateReader()
        Select Case Driver.Name
            Case "drivers"
                output += "Drivers:" + vbCrLf
                Dim drv = Driver.Value
                Dim drvProp As List(Of JToken) = drv.Children().ToList
                For Each DriverProperty As JProperty In drvProp
                    Select Case DriverProperty.Name 'e.t.c...
```

Thanks!

Comment: [VB.Net Simple Json Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25029243/1115360) might be very useful to you.

Comment: Deserialze, change the items, Serialize

Comment: Andrew Morton, thanks a lot. it was very usefull!